# Rails form using jQuery Delete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to immediately delete part of my form when user clicks a link_to using jQuery and I've referred to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM

Issue is, after deleting, the field is hidden however, if the user fails a validation or refresh the page, the field appears again. Only upon successful validation and the form is save then will the data be deleted.

I wish to apply jQuery such that once the delete button is click, it is immediately deleted and even after a failed validation or user refresh the page, the section deleted will not appear again.

The following is the code on the section i'm trying to delete:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.check_box :mon %>Mon
  <%= f.check_box :tue %>Tue
  <%= f.check_box :wed %>Wed
  <%= f.check_box :thur %>Thur
  <%= f.check_box :fri %>Fri
  <%= f.check_box :sat %>Sat
  <%= f.check_box :sun %>Sun
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete deal period', '#', class: 'remove_fields' %><br/><br/>
  <%= f.fields_for :deal_times do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'form/deal_time_form', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_time "Add timing", f, :deal_times %>
</fieldset>
```

The following is my jQuery

```
$ ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')eve
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you reload a page the javascripts gets reloaded,it would be good if you can handle it through action , like add a flag variable inside action which will decide the visibility of the field .And upon click event you just change the flag .

Comment: Thanks for your ans. However, I am not certain how to implement this.
I tried including this $(this).closest('fieldset').addClass('hidden') and it doesn't work as well.